# I've got a splunk dashboard, 2 of the panels are sized correctly, but the thirds height seems to be tied to the firsts no matter what I change

Tags: html, xml, layout, splunk

I have the following code for a dashboard, which was working perfectly until I added the Model Name and Size panel which is near the end of the code. I've been using #singlevalue_ to set layout for each individual panel, which works for the "Models in Selected Workspace Set" width and for "Space Remaining in Each Workspace" height and width. The "Model Name and Size" panel is set to 300 px, which kind of works, but the panel extends past the panel contents by another 300px, which matches the max height of dashboard panels. How do I force the whitespace at the bottom of the panel to adhere to 300px?

```
<form>
   <label>L3 recreate model Activity</label>
   <description>Lists the models in descending order of last time used in the L3 recreate workspaces and their sizes for archival purposes</description>
   <fieldset submitButton="false"></fieldset>
   <row>
     <panel id="singleValuePanel1">
       <title>Models in Selected Workspace Set</title>
       <input type="dropdown" token="set" searchWhenChanged="true">
         <label>Workspace Set</label>
         <default>8a81948243cb6a7f0143d9ff2be97e34</default>
         <initialValue>8a81948243cb6a7f0143d9ff2be97e34</initialValue>
         <fieldForLabel>workspaceName</fieldForLabel>
         <fieldForValue>workspaceGuid</fieldForValue>
         <search>
           <query>workspaceGuid=8a81b09c53248e3d0153f1cab02d7dc5 OR workspaceGuid=8a81948243cb6a7f0143d9ff2be97e34 OR workspaceGuid=8a819488482885c901483c882c6c4fa9 OR workspaceGuid=8a81b0945ef8a5c0015f255c3f8e44a2 | dedup workspaceGuid | stats count by workspaceGuid | lookup model-all workspaceGuid</query>
           <earliest>-24h@h</earliest>
           <latest>now</latest>
         </search>
       </input>
       <input type="text" token="sizeGB" searchWhenChanged="true">
         <label>Size Threshold(GB)</label>
         <default>1</default>
       </input>
        <html>
          <style>
           .dashboard-row .dashboard-panel .panel-element-row {
               overflow: auto;
               max-height: 600px;
            }
             #singleValuePanel1{
               width: 65% !important;
             }
          </style>
        </html>
       <table>
         <search>
           <query>index=core sourcetype=core $set$ GET_LOGGED_IN_USER=1
 | eval lastseen=strftime(_time, "%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S")
 | stats first(lastseen) by modelGuid
 | sort + lastseen
 | lookup model-all modelGuid output modelName as "Model Name" workspaceName as "Workspace Name" 
 | lookup model-dc5prod modelGuid output activeState memoryUsage
 | eval "Model Size(GB)" = round(memoryUsage / 1073741824,4)
 | search "Model Size(GB)" &gt;$sizeGB$
 | search activeState!=ARCHIVED 
 | table "Workspace Name", "Model Name", activeState, first(lastseen), "Model Size(GB)"</query>
           <earliest>-60d</earliest>
           <latest>now</latest>
           <sampleRatio>1</sampleRatio>
         </search>
         <option name="count">50</option>
         <option name="dataOverlayMode">none</option>
         <option name="drilldown">none</option>
         <option name="percentagesRow">false</option>
         <option name="rowNumbers">false</option>
         <option name="totalsRow">false</option>
         <option name="wrap">true</option>
       </table>
     </panel>
     <panel id="singleValuePanel2">
       <title>Space Remaining in Each Workspace</title>
       <html depends="$hiddenForCSS$">
         <style>
           #singleValuePanel2{
             height: 200px !important;
             width: 35% !important;
           }
         </style>
       </html>
       <table>
         <search>
           <query>workspaceGuid=8a81b09c53248e3d0153f1cab02d7dc5 OR workspaceGuid=8a81948243cb6a7f0143d9ff2be97e34 OR workspaceGuid=8a819488482885c901483c882c6c4fa9 OR workspaceGuid=8a81b0945ef8a5c0015f255c3f8e44a2
 | fields + workspaceSize, workspaceGuid
 | lookup workspace-dc5prod workspaceGuid output name
 | stats latest(workspaceSize) by name
 | appendcols 
     [| inputlookup workspace-dc5prod where workspaceGuid=8a81b09c53248e3d0153f1cab02d7dc5 OR workspaceGuid=8a81948243cb6a7f0143d9ff2be97e34 OR workspaceGuid=8a819488482885c901483c882c6c4fa9 OR workspaceGuid=8a81b0945ef8a5c0015f255c3f8e44a2 
     | eval sizeAllowance= sizeAllowance/ 1073741824
     | stats values(sizeAllowance) by name ]
 | convert num(latest(workspaceSize)) as workspaceSize, num(values(sizeAllowance)) as sizeAllowance
 | eval "Space Remaining(GB)"=sizeAllowance-workspaceSize
 | table name "Space Remaining(GB)" workspaceSize sizeAllowance
 | rename workspaceSize as "Space Used(GB)" sizeAllowance as "Size Allowance(GB)"</query>
           <earliest>-24h</earliest>
           <latest>now</latest>
           <sampleRatio>1</sampleRatio>
         </search>
         <option name="count">50</option>
         <option name="dataOverlayMode">none</option>
         <option name="drilldown">none</option>
         <option name="percentagesRow">false</option>
         <option name="rowNumbers">false</option>
         <option name="totalsRow">false</option>
         <option name="wrap">true</option>
       </table>
     </panel>
     <panel id="singleValuePanel">
       <title>Lookup Model Name and Size</title>
       <input type="text" token="mGuid">
         <label>Model Guid</label>
       </input>
       <html>
         <style>
           #singleValuePanel{
             max-height: 300px !important;
             width: 35% !important;
           }
         </style>
         </html>
       <table>
         <search>
           <query>| inputlookup model-all
 | where modelGuid="$mGuid$"
 | eval "Model Size(GB)"=round(lastModelSizeBytes/1000000000, 2)
 | fields + customerName workspaceName modelName "Model Size(GB)"
 | rename workspaceName as "Workspace Name" customerName as "Customer" modelName as "Model Name"</query>
           <earliest>-24h</earliest>
           <latest>now</latest>
           <sampleRatio>1</sampleRatio>
         </search>
         <option name="count">1</option>
         <option name="dataOverlayMode">none</option>
         <option name="drilldown">none</option>
         <option name="percentagesRow">false</option>
         <option name="rowNumbers">false</option>
         <option name="totalsRow">false</option>
         <option name="wrap">true</option>
       </table>
     </panel>
   </row>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd add this to your code at the bottom.

```
#singleValuePanel{
    max-height: 300px !important;
    width: 35% !important;
    margin-bottom: 20px !important;
}
```

This should give you the desired white space under the Model Name and Size panel. Adjust the px as needed within the margin-bottom field to give more or less room.